# Error in JS theme: Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I'm trying to animate a view, I'm inserting this code into a js but I have problems on the line 84, in:

```
function trigger_accordion(item-slide) {
if(!(item-slide.is(':animated'))) {
    item-slide.trigger('open');
}
}
```

The error is printed: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Attach the full code:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

    var animation = {
        'auto_animate': true,
        'auto_animate_delay': 8000,
        'auto_animate_id': '',
        'caption_speed': 'fast',
        //'panel_speed': 'slow',
        'panel_speed': 1000,
        'panel_easing': 'easeInOutCubic'
    }

Drupal.behaviors.pamh_theme = {
    attach: function(context, settings) { 

$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;
    $('.item-slide').each(function(key, value) {
        $(value).attr('id', 'item-slide-'+i);
        i++;
    });

    $('.slide_caption').hide();
    $('#item-slide-1 > .slide_caption').show();
    $('#item-slide-1').addClass('active');
    $('.item-slide').not('.active').children('.slide_image_slice').show();

    });



    $('.item-slide')
    .bind('open', function(){       
        if(! $(this).hasClass('open')){
            $(this).next().trigger('open');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).animate({right: "-=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
        }
        else{
            $(this).prev().trigger('close');
        }
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){hide_slices()},1);


        display_caption();
    })
    .bind('close', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')){
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).animate({right: "+=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
            $(this).prev().trigger('close');
        }
    });

$('.item-slide')
    .hoverIntent(
        function() {
            animation.auto_animate = false;
            trigger_accordion($(this));
        },
        function() {
            animation.auto_animate = true;
            clearInterval(animation.auto_animate_id);
            animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval('slideshow_animate()', animation.auto_animate_delay);
        }
    )
    .click(function() {
        trigger_accordion($(this));
    });

animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval('slideshow_animate()', animation.auto_animate_delay);

};

function trigger_accordion(item-slide) {
if(!(item-slide.is(':animated'))) {
    item-slide.trigger('open');
}
}

function display_caption() {
    $('.slide_caption').each(function() {
        if(!($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))) {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('.item-slide.active >     .slide_caption').fadeIn(animation.caption_speed);
            });
        }
    });
}

function hide_slices() {
    $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
}

function display_slices() {
    $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active') && !$(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
}

function slideshow_animate() {
    if(!animation.auto_animate) return;

    var next_slide = $('.item-slide.active').next();
    if(!next_slide.length) {
        next_slide = $('#item-slide-1');
    }

    next_slide.click();

}
};
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: I think you are missing a closing `)` for your `$(document).ready` call. Proper code indentation would certainly help find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- You cannot name javascript variables with the `-` character like you did with `item-slide`. It is OK with CSS classes, but with javascript you have to find something else.
- You had a misplaced closing bracket `}`. Here is the full code that works for me:

  ```
  (function ($, Drupal) {

  var animation = {
      'auto_animate': true,
      'auto_animate_delay': 8000,
      'auto_animate_id': '',
      'caption_speed': 'fast',
      //'panel_speed': 'slow',
      'panel_speed': 1000,
      'panel_easing': 'easeInOutCubic'
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.pamh_theme = {
      attach: function(context, settings) { 

          $(document).ready(function(){

              var i = 1;
              $('.item-slide').each(function(key, value) {
                  $(value).attr('id', 'item-slide-'+i);
                  i++;
              });

              $('.slide_caption').hide();
              $('#item-slide-1 > .slide_caption').show();
              $('#item-slide-1').addClass('active');
              $('.item-slide').not('.active').children('.slide_image_slice').show();

          });



          $('.item-slide')
          .bind('open', function(){       
              if(! $(this).hasClass('open')){
                  $(this).next().trigger('open');
                  $(this).addClass('open');
                  $(this).animate({right: "-=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
              }
              else{
                  $(this).prev().trigger('close');
              }
              $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
              $(this).addClass('active');
              setTimeout(function(){hide_slices()},1);


              display_caption();
          })
          .bind('close', function(){
              if($(this).hasClass('open')){
                  $(this).removeClass('open');
                  $(this).animate({right: "+=769px"}, animation.panel_speed, animation.panel_easing, function(){display_slices();});
                  $(this).prev().trigger('close');
              }
          });

          $('.item-slide')
          .hoverIntent(
              function() {
                  animation.auto_animate = false;
                  trigger_accordion($(this));
              },
              function() {
                  animation.auto_animate = true;
                  clearInterval(animation.auto_animate_id);
                  animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval('slideshow_animate()', animation.auto_animate_delay);
              }
          )
          .click(function() {
              trigger_accordion($(this));
          });

          animation.auto_animate_id = setInterval('slideshow_animate()', animation.auto_animate_delay);
      }
  };

  function trigger_accordion(itemSlide) {
      if(!(itemSlide.is(':animated'))) {
          itemSlide.trigger('open');
      }
  }

  function display_caption() {
      $('.slide_caption').each(function() {
          if(!($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))) {
              $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                  $('.item-slide.active >     .slide_caption').fadeIn(animation.caption_speed);
              });
          }
      });
  }

  function hide_slices() {
      $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
          if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
              $(this).fadeOut('fast');
          }
      });
  }

  function display_slices() {
      $('.slide_image_slice').each(function() {
          if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('active') && !$(this).is(":visible")) {
              $(this).fadeIn('fast');
          }
      });
  }

  function slideshow_animate() {
      if(!animation.auto_animate) return;

      var next_slide = $('.item-slide.active').next();
      if(!next_slide.length) {
          next_slide = $('#item-slide-1');
      }

      next_slide.click();

  }
  })(jQuery, Drupal);
  ```